# Counting pairs in a table, excel

Tags: excel

I have a table consisting of character names in excel

***Small section of table:***
[image]

I'm looking to count the number of times a pair occurs in a row. eg the number of times `yasuo` and `atroxx` appear (3) or the amount of times `zoe` and zed appear (2) I've tried `countifs()` but that doesn't work and am looking for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For long table it would be easier to solve the issue if you have `Excel-365`. Try below formula with `Excel-365`.

```
=SUM(MMULT(--(A2:E7="aatrox"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:E2),,,0))*(MMULT(--(A2:E7="yasuo"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:E2),,,0))))
```

For older versions of excel try-

```
=SUM(MMULT(--(A2:E7="aatrox"),TRANSPOSE({1,1,1,1,1}))*(MMULT(--(A2:E7="yasuo"),TRANSPOSE({1,1,1,1,1}))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can transform this question to 3 steps:

1. you count/countif wheather the name in each row;
2. you calculate weather the numbers of each target name appears are bigger than 1;
3. finally, sum the 0/1 result and you get the answer;

[image: one demo]